# Copy only file reference using rsync

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm trying to sync two directories, but with a catch: I want my destination folder to have a zero byte file if the corresponding full file exists in the source. Is this possible using rsync or is there any other linux alternative?

Comment: Your question would be better asked on http://superuser.com